# Why not this reflective-size set theory be the foundational theory of sets?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Language: first order logic with equality + primitives of membership $\in$ and a constant $W$ signifying the world of all sets.

Axioms:

**Extensionality:** $\forall z (z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y) \to x=y$

**Comprehension:** $\exists x: x=\{y \in W| \phi\} $; if $x$ doesn't occur in $\phi$

**Reflection:** $\forall\vec{x} \in W [\exists x \phi \to \exists x \in W \phi]$; if $\phi$ in $L(=,\in)$ with all parameters from $\vec{x}$.

**Size:** $ x \in W \leftrightarrow x \subset W \land |x|<|W|$

**Foundation:** $x \neq \emptyset \to \exists y \in x (y \cap x =\emptyset)$

/Theory definition finished.

Now to me the above axiomatic system looks very "natural". All notions encountered in its axioms are pretty much elementary of logic and set conception. However this theory proves to be so strong relative to ZFC, its consistency strength is near to a Mahlo. In my own experience I know of no consistent theory that is presented in alike elementary manner and at the same time enjoying such strength. Possibly "ZFC + CH fails for every multipleton set" is of comparable elementary presentation, and it is much stronger than this, however the semantics of it are much more complicated and its not immediately clear how it conforms with the usual semantics of ZFC, that it cannot be regarded as constituting a direct extension of it. However with the above theory we do have a motivation that directly flow from conceptions about ZFC itself, that in some sense can be seen as a direct extension of it much as ZFC itself can be seen as a natural extension of Zermelo. This line of theories can show a nice spectrum, if we change "size" axiom by "$W$ is transitive", we get a theory of a strength in the vicinity of second order arithmetic, if we instead replace it by the axiom stating that "every subset of an element of $W$ is an element of $W$", then we get a theory in the strength of ZFC. So the theory here comes as a upgrade of that up to size limitation which blows it up to near Mahlo strength. I advocate this set theory to be the maximal of known naturally looking set theories.

Now I see a tendency to coin mathematical-formal concepts in the hereditarily accessible sets of ZFC, since that's what the axioms of ZFC can grant, the underlying rationale is that discourse about those sets is granted by the most natural conception about sets that is embodied by ZFC. However, here I'd suggest that this limit of naturalness that's built after whats granted to exists after ZFC, is to be set up to instead be what's granted to exist by this theory! As this theory can be viewed as an embodiment of natural conceptions about sets, since it extends ZFC from conceptions inherent to ZFC itself and is expressed in a quite elementary manner.

Question: What mathematical arguments can be raised against this stance? I'm not asking for a philosophical opinion here! I'm asking about a mathematical technical workup that can in some sense invalidate this approach, or can show that adopting this theory to organize thought about sets can cause impediments with some advanced techniques that ZFC grants in a flawless manner, that makes it unworthy of being considered as a foundation of natural set theoretic thought?

Comment: I'm not a logician, so this may be stupid : isn't this the theory of classes and sets?

Comment: @user44191, you mean Muller's. http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/1372/1/SetClassCat.PDF

Comment: @user44191, I don't know which theory of classes and sets you have in your mind, the known theories are NBG, MK, Ackermann's, Muller's, and Quine's ML. In any case this theory is way stronger than all of those.

Comment: This theory looks similar to ones considered by Bernays in "Zur Frage der Unendlichkeitsschemata in der axiomatischen Mengenlehre" (there is an English translation, "On the Problem of Schemata of Infinity in Axiomatic Set Theory").